# Does "price of delayed order" mean same as "delayed order price"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Do these two phrases have the same meaning?

> 1. price of delayed order
> 2. delayed order price

I think they are the same, but I'm not sure. Which is more common and less difficult to understand if there is a significant difference?

Comment: Strange 5 persons edited question but still no answer :)

Comment: I would include some reference and the context if i were you. People on SE tend to ignore questions with general reference or no reference at all.

Comment: Example: "See a price of delayed order." or "See delayed order price"?

Answer (score 2):

It may be stretching it, but I think they *could* have different implications:

1. "price of delayed order" could mean the (total) price of the order, which happens to have been delayed (and/or distinguishing it from another order which wasn't delayed).
2. "delayed order price" could be the (extra) cost incurred as a result of the order being (or having been) delayed.

But it depends on context!

Comment: O.K. If the context will be the same meaning of both will be the same (I am not native speaker)?